# Dequeueing different sized 'items'

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have a problem in which I have a bit steam coming in faster than I can process the necessary results (error correction is slow)

I decided the best way to do this would be to queue the stream and remove chunks of it when ready. I do some very quick processing to determine the size of the chunk, before placing it in the queue.

When I try to remove the chunk from the queue all information about it's size has been lost, and q.get() just returns the size of the last chunk placed in the queue(which will not be the same size as the original chunk). This is a problem as the processing strips and removes bits of the data depending on their position in the bit stream chunk. So if the chunk is shorter the wrong bits are removed, and the information contained is lost.

So how can I use q.get() to extract the right sized 'item' from the queue?

Here is my simplified code (but it is not that helpful):

```
q = Queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
rq = Queue.Queue(maxsize=0)

def dosomething(q, rq)
    data = q.get()
    #process data (takes a few seconds)
    q.task_done()
    rq.put(processed_data)


sock.timeout = 5.00
while True:
    try:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(65536)
        chunk = data[0:x]  # where x is the length of data needed
        q.put_nowait(chunk)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=dosomething, args=(q, rq,))
        thread.start()
    except RuntimeError:
        continue
    except socket.timeout:
        break

print(rq.get())
rq.task_done()
thread.join()
```

Here is what the outcome is if the bit stream were to come across in chunks of sizes 5, 4, 3, 2, and 1:

-If the input is slow, so that there is never more than one item in the queue, the output chunk sizes are 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.

-If the input is fast so that the queue grows, the output chunk sizes are something like 3, 1, 1, 1, 1.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error! Bad naming conventions are the problem, and I ended up using a global variable data stream instead of the stored one. Sorry